# Bootstrap modal does not activate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a Navbar button that calls a bootstrap modal which contains a form. I found a gist at https://gist.github.com/havvg/3226804, and I'm trying to adapt it to my needs. I haven'y completed filling out the ajax portion of the script, but I notice that the modal does not activate. i want to press the button on the navbar and have the modal form pop up. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="hide fade modal" id="rating-modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">button</button>
         <h2>Your Review</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- The async form to send and replace the modals content with its response -->
        <form class="form-horizontal well" id="modalForm" data-async data-target="#rating-modal" action="AjaxUpdate/modal" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>modalForm</legend <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="old">Old password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input id="old" name="old" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
                        <p class="help-block">help</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="new">New password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input id="new" name="new" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
                        <p class="help-block">help</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>

    </div>
</div>
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

     //    $('form[data-async]').live('submit', function(event) {
     $('#modalForm').on('submit', function (event) {
         var $form = $(this);
         var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));

         $.ajax({
             type: $form.attr('method'),
             url: $form.attr('action'),
             data: $form.serialize(),

             success: function (data, status) {
                 $target.html(data);
             }
         });

         event.preventDefault();
     });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: 1st things 1st, change `live` to `on`

Comment: which version of jquery ? `live` needs to be replaced with `.on`

Comment: done - please see above

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the class `hide` from your div:
`<div class="fade modal" id="rating-modal">`